# Неожиданный конец файла во время поиска «"» + Синтаксическая ошибка: неожиданный конец файла

Tags: linux, bash

Пишет, что ошибка в 7 и 10 строчке соответственно. А что в них, собственно, не так?

```
 #!/bin/bash

if   [ "$1 == "Vasya" ]; then
    echo "Privet $1"
elif [ "$1" == "Traump" ]; then
    echo "Hello $1"
else echo "Zdarova $1"
fi
```

Comment: О какой 10-й строке речь, если в вашем примере 8 строк? А без пустой строки вообще 7. Похоже, код левый.

Comment: @freim либеральный? )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы потеряли `"` в 3 строке.

Замените на:

```
#!/bin/bash

if   [ "$1" == "Vasya" ]; then
    echo "Privet $1"
elif [ "$1" == "Traump" ]; then
    echo "Hello $1"
else echo "Zdarova $1"
fi
```

Comment: Пробовал, но ситуация не изменилась

Comment: @Romualdo а кавычки после `$1` добавили в 3 строке?